# jQuery Mobile Site Viewed from Android Webview is Different than Device Browser

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, webkit, android-webview

I have an Android app with a web view that displays a jQuery Mobile site. The mobile site behaves a bit differently in the web view than it does in the device's browser.

In the site, I use a static header and a panel. In the device's browser, this works normally with the header sliding to the left when the panel is opened (please see below):

[image]

However, when loaded via the app's web view, the static header stays 100% of the width of the screen and covers the first of the three buttons (please see below):

[image]

Also, the jQuery mobile responses are much more glitchy/sticky when using the app, and are very smooth when using the device's browser. I have pasted the code for my web view class below:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


class MyClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
            Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}

public class locationPage extends Activity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.embed);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/testWebClient");

        webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/mobile_site/index");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyClient());

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { 
            @Override 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
{ 
                view.loadUrl(url); 
                return true; 
            } 


    }
}
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) { 
            webView.goBack(); 
            return true; 
        } 
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using HTML5 and css, my page's UI is completely destroyed when using WebView.

Differences in imnage positions and zoom level and as stated static menus.

Page linking works even when using $mobile.changePage function but pages flickers back and forth. Maybe i need to remove Jquery page linking and inject page dynamically without JQM. This is not recommended on browsers since you loose the history.

Static menu not moving is my desired outcome, so thats a plus for WebView. as well as the full screen offered by webview.

I will research some more and post something if i find any workarounds.

JQM performance so far is horrible in both scenarios and im fetching data from localstorage. I've expected the performance to be a lot better.....